# Using insert_all only inserts one record and it's not the first one

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm new to developing with this stack and framework. I'm using Ecto 3.4 and based on my understanding reading the documentation and looking at what I have found on the web this should insert all of the records in my units. I've tried cleaning, recompiling, and also resetting the database. This is in a module which is being called from seeds.exs. I have a lot of need to seed data so I wanted to clean it up. It feels almost like the code is stale because the only record it's inserting is not the first one and there are now more records to seed.

```
  def seed do
    timestamp =
      NaiveDateTime.utc_now()
      |> NaiveDateTime.truncate(:second)

    units = [
      %{abbreviation: "tsp", unit: "teaspoon", standard: "U.S.", inserted_at: timestamp, updated_at: timestamp},
      %{abbreviation: "tbsp", unit: "tablespoon", standard: "U.S.", inserted_at: timestamp, updated_at: timestamp},
      %{abbreviation: "oz", unit: "ounces", standard: "U.S.", inserted_at: timestamp, updated_at: timestamp},
      %{abbreviation: "fl oz", unit: "fluid ounce", standard: "U.S.", inserted_at: timestamp, updated_at: timestamp},
      %{abbreviation: "cup", unit: "cup", standard: "U.S.", inserted_at: timestamp, updated_at: timestamp},
      %{abbreviation: "pt", unit: "pint", standard: "U.S.", inserted_at: timestamp, updated_at: timestamp},
      %{abbreviation: "qt", unit: "quart", standard: "U.S.", inserted_at: timestamp, updated_at: timestamp},
      %{abbreviation: "gal", unit: "gallon", standard: "U.S.", inserted_at: timestamp, updated_at: timestamp},
      %{abbreviation: "lb", unit: "pound", standard: "U.S.", inserted_at: timestamp, updated_at: timestamp},
      %{abbreviation: "l", unit: "liter", standard: "Metric", inserted_at: timestamp, updated_at: timestamp},
      %{abbreviation: "ml", unit: "milliliter", standard: "Metric", inserted_at: timestamp, updated_at: timestamp},
      %{abbreviation: "g", unit: "grams", standard: "Metric", inserted_at: timestamp, updated_at: timestamp},
      %{abbreviation: "kg", unit: "kilograms", standard: "Metric", inserted_at: timestamp, updated_at: timestamp}
    ]

    Foo.Repo.insert_all(Unit, units)
  end
```

Is there something I have as a mistake here or is it possible there is something to unstick here? I already deleted the build directory.

Comment: The code looks fine, but it makes probably more sense to use [`Ecto.Multi.insert_all/5`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html?#insert_all/5). In any case, please share what DB do you use (I suspect MySQL, since truncation to a single random record in any unclear situation is its birth injury) and what indices/unique keys does this table have.

Comment: It's actually postgres. I'm just getting back to messing with it. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Also, when you `IO.inspect` the `unit` variable, can you see something?